# In flex, how to get global coordinate position of a component?

Tags: apache-flex, components, global

In flex, how to get global coordinate position of a component?

Comment: Duplicate of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444177/in-flex-how-to-get-cooridnates-when-using-vbox-for-stacking-up-components)...

Comment: More or less. It's the same problem anyway. Call localToGlobal() on the component you want to know the position on.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `localToGlobal(point :Point)` method of a `DisplayObject`.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal()