# In flex, how to get coordinates when using VBox for stacking up components?

Tags: apache-flex, coordinates, vbox

In flex, I am using VBox & HBox to stack components. When I try to get  x,y coordinate of a component, I always get 0. If I specify coordinate like mx:VBox x="120", then I get the value.

How can I get the coordinate without explicitly stating it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or what results you're getting.  Can you share some code?

Comment: mx:AddChild relativeTo="{mainBox}"
    mx:VBox id="box1" verticalGap="0" width="100%"
          <mx:Text  id="directionsHelp" color="#4FA4CD" fontSize="8" fontWeight="bold"
         mx:htmlText
      [CDATA[(temp data)]]>
  mx:htmlText
   mx:Text>
    mx:VBox

Comment: Now, if I try to get the y-coordinate of directonsHelp, I get 0. I even tried localToGlobal method but the result is 0 too. I guessed maybe it has something to do with the way components are stacked? the question is: why I am getting value 0 and not the correct y-cordinate?

Comment: so the question is, can we get X-coordinate if components are stacked relatively?

Comment: Put the code in your main question and format it a bit better.  It appears that you're using the "AddChild" class which a Flex 3 state handling class.  Are you sure you moved into the state that adds the child?

Answer (score 2):

You can translate the coordinates relatively to the stage. Check out the code below:

```
var box:VBox = new VBox;
var child:DisplayObject = new DisplayObject;

box.addChild(child);

child.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, updateCompleteHandler);

...

private function updateCompleteHandler(fe:FlexEvent):void{
  // find global coordinates
  var globalCoords:Point = child.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));

  // coordsInBox is what you are looking for
  var coordsInBox:Point = box.globalToLocal(globalCoords); 
}
```

The point is to use `localToGlobal` for the child components and then `globalToLocal` to translate the global coordinates so that they were expressed relatively to the box container.

Please notice, that the coordinates won't be processed until `UPDATE_COMPLETE` is called by the child object.

Answer (score 0):

The X and Y values of a component are always relative to the component's parent. `directionsHelp.x` and `directionsHelp.y` will both return the position relative to the VBox containing them which, unless you explicitly set the values or insert other components around it, will be 0 by default.

The thing to remember about `localToGlobal()` is that you must call it from the child. If you have an `Application` and you just call `localToGlobal( new Point(child.x, child.y) )`, it will try to return the given point within the Application relative to the stage (because you haven't specified what "local" is), which will therefore conduct no transformations, and it will therefore stay equal to (0, 0).

If however you call `child.localToGlobal( new Point(child.x, child.y) )`, it will return the value of the child's position relative to the stage, transforming the given point by however much the child is offset on the stage.

Here's a quick app to demonstrate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"    backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function updateCoords():void
            {
                var point:Point = new Point(directionsHelp.x, directionsHelp.y);
                point = directionsHelp.localToGlobal(point);
                directionsHelp.text = "My stage coordinates are ("+point.x+", "+point.y+")";
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Box height="100" width="100" borderStyle="solid" borderColor="#000000"
            horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Label text="100 x 100" />
        </mx:Box>
        <mx:VBox>
            <mx:Text id="directionsHelp" color="#4FA4CD" fontSize="8" fontWeight="bold"
                text="Click the button to display my position on the stage." />
            <mx:Button label="Get Position" click="updateCoords()" />
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: If you have a component in a VBox the x and y values of that component are ignored; and will most likely be reset by the VBox layout logic.

Comment: Not true afaik. Add `+", local coords are ("+directionsHelp.x+", "+directionsHelp.y+")";` to my `directionsHelp.text` assignment above, and then copy the 100x100 box above the `directionsHelp` Text control, and the output will be:

`My stage coordinates are (0, 318), local (0, 106)`

So the local X and Y coordinates of the Text control have been updated by the VBox layout logic.